# URL rewrite and redirect between hosts

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, host, redirect

I have the following rewrite rule to redirect any conetnt from a host, hostA.com to the home page of a new host, hostB.com. *I also want to browser url to change to www.HostB.com*

```
<rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="301 redirect entire site" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^hostA(.*)$" />
                <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="http://www.hostB.com" appendQueryString="true" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

But that does not work. How can I fix this please.

Comment: what does the ouput look like what http error you are getting, or the redirection rule is not being applied ?

Comment: It is being applied but the browser url does not change. Furthermore, I had to add a binding to the new host on the old host. I do not know if this is necessary after setting the DNS.

Answer (score 1):

you can doit like this

```
<rule name="domain redirect" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^hostA(.*)$" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://hostb.example.com/{R:0}" appendQueryString="true" />
  </rule>
```

Comment: so to redirect to just the home page of hostb, I need to change the last line to <action type="Redirect" url="http://hostb.example.com" appendQueryString="true" />. Right?

Comment: for some reason, the brower url does not change but the redirect occurs.